# Conditional update of pandas dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a master dataframe with two sets of values:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id1': [1, 1, 2, 2],
               'dir1': [True, False, True, False],
               'value1': [55, 40, 84, 31],
               'id2': [3, 3, 4, 4],
               'dir2': [True, False, False, True],
               'value2': [60, 30, 7, 15]})

   id1   dir1  value1  id2   dir2  value2
0    1   True      55    3   True      60
1    1  False      40    3  False      30
2    2   True      84    4  False       7
3    2  False      31    4   True      15
```

I then have an update dataframe that looks like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
               'value': [21, 22, 23, 24]})
   id  value
0   1     21
1   2     22
2   3     23
3   4     24
```

I want to update df1 with the new values of df2 but only where dirX is True.  Data should then look like this:

```
   id1   dir1  value1  id2   dir2  value2
0    1   True     *21    3   True     *23
1    1  False      40    3  False      30
2    2   True     *22    4  False       7
3    2  False      31    4   True     *24
```

Any idea if something like this is even possible?  I tried looking at .update but I could not get it to work.  I'm fairly new to python and only coding at 23:00, so maybe I'm just not as sharp as I need to be.

Comment: Hi, why you are not looping through df1 and change values when dirX is true?

Comment: I love loops, but what I've learned about pandas is, loops are your VERY last resort.  Always way slow and way inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Thales' answer. First, you merge df2 with df1 based on id1:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='id1', right_on='id')
```

Then, you replace `value1` based on `dir1` with `value`:

```
df.value1 = np.where(df.dir1 == True, df.value, df.value1)
```

Then, you drop the extra columns

```
df = df.drop(['id', 'value'],axis=1)
```

Then, you merge df2 with df1 based on `id2`:

```
df = df.merge(df2, left_on='id2', right_on='id')
```

Do the same replacing, but for `value2`

```
df.value2 = np.where(df.dir2 == True, df.value, df.value2)
```

Then, drop the extra columns:

```
df = df.drop(['id', 'value'],axis=1)
```

The resulting dataframe will look like:

```
   id1   dir1  value1  id2   dir2  value2
0    1   True      21    3   True      23
1    1  False      40    3  False      30
2    2   True      22    4  False       7
3    2  False      31    4   True      24
```

Comment: Like a charm!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use np.where function from numpy.

Maybe something like this:

```
df_1['value1'] = np.where(df_1['dir2'] == True, df_2['value'], df_1['value1'])
```

Maybe you'll need some adjustments or some merges, but I think this will help you to find a solution.